# How can I use single model with multiple entities in Room Android?

Tags: java, database, android-room

I have a problem with Android Room Database.
I have a dictionary database that contains two tables with every column have the same name.

This is the code:

```
@Entity(tableName = "eng_dictionary")
public class EnglishDictionary {
    @PrimaryKey
    protected Integer id = null;
    protected @NonNull
    String word = "";
    protected @NonNull
    String translation = "";
    protected @NonNull
    String related_words = "";
}
```

And

```
@Entity(tableName = "krn_dictionary")
public class KoreanDictionary {
    @PrimaryKey
    protected Integer id = null;
    protected @NonNull
    String word = "";
    protected @NonNull
    String translation = "";
    protected @NonNull
    String related_words = "";
}
```

are same, can I use one model with multiple entities?

Comment: Why don't you add additional column for the language instead of having a separate table for each?

Comment: because it contains a different thing.